# Can't grant access to to contextual gmail gadget

Tags: google-schemas

I have created a manifest and a gadget file.  I uploaded the manifest and made the gadget available on the web.  I deployed the application and verified it was in my google apps domain.  However when I go to  Admin Console->Market Place Apps->My App Name.  it shows that I need to grant access.  When I click grant data access it opens a new pages and starts to load, but nothing but the header ever load.

I can see google retrieving the gadget file from my webserver, but the gadget doesn't seme to be working in gmail and I see no indication it has been loaded.  I am using the ?nogadgetcache=1 flag.

I have tried using a couple of supposed working examples and always get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very simple: On November 2013 Google has changed the way to grant data access, but the `developers.google.com` page remained as is.
To make your gadget follow this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing
I saw it in another stackoverflow page... ([GMail Contextual Gadget not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362541))

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to deploy the gadget. Even after I mark the `COB extension` checkbox, I am required to mark another checkbox, I don't which and don't know why. Please someone will help me...