# Gmail contextual gadget data access

Tags: xml, gmail, manifest, google-apps, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I tried to make a gmail contextual gadget, wrote a manifest xml file and a gadget xml file.
Then I entered into google apps page, uploaded the manifest file and clicked on `deploy application`.
A new tab opened on the browser, asked for `grant data access`. Of course I granted.
Then I was redirected to `admin console` page, and in the `marketplace apps` I could see that the data access is still not approved. I clicked again on "grant data access" but it affected nothing. The context of the window disappeared, and the next time I entered into marketplace apps it remained as it was.

Why it happened and how can I solve it?

I attach here the manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/ApplicationManifest/2009">
    <Name>try13</Name>
    <Description>Synchronize Gmail with Tasks</Description>

    <Extension id = "RecipientEmailExtractor" type = "contextExtractor">
        <Name>Recipient email extractor</Name>
        <Url>google.com:RecipientEmailExtractor</Url>
        <Param name = "recipient_email" value = ".*"/>
        <Triggers ref = "PriorityGmailGadget"/>
        <Scope ref = "emailtoAddress"/>
        <Container name = "mail"/>
    </Extension>

<!-- GADGET -->
    <Extension id="PriorityGmailGadget" type="gadget">
      <Name>try 13 Gmail Sync Gadget</Name>
      <Url>https://gadgetsource.com/google/emptyGadget.xml</Url>
      <Container name="mail"/>
    </Extension>

    <!-- SCOPE -->
    <Scope id="emailtoAddress">
         <Url>tag:google.com,2010:auth/contextual/extractor/TO_ADDRESS</Url>
        <Reason>Find a Priority contact with this email address</Reason>
     </Scope>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

Comment: Have you installed the other gadgets already (for instance the sample gadgets)?

Comment: What is your gadget source? Is it accessible on the internet?

Comment: @rds I got old files of manifest, extractor and gadget which worked in past, but a new customer of out company gets the same result as I get. I tried to minimize the manifest and gadget codes, and not to use extractor file, but the same result still occurs. Do you see any problem in manifest file? Do you think the gadget file is relevant to this problem? I think the problem is only in the manifest, because the field of data which need a premission are defined there. Am I wrong?

Comment: @rds I didn't try to install sample gadgets, and the gadget file is not accessible in the internet. It stay on our server.

Comment: I found that this question was asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362541, but I still confused :(.  `Alex` answered there that Google changed the way to grant data access and provided a link. I followed the instructions in this link, but I can't make the gadget as a contextual one. Google doesn't recognize this gadget as an email-depend and it appears in the navigation app always as an independent app. How can I assign the gadget to email?